# Custom video cropping using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm using the writingminds ffmpeg library for cropping the video and getting the height, width ,x and y coordinates via a custom selector. 
I'm using the following code for cropping :

```
 String[] cmd = {"-i", path, "-filter:v", "crop=" + valuewidth + ":" + 
 valueheight + ":" + valuex + ":" + valuey, "-c:a", "copy", videoPath};
 execFFmpegBinary(cmd);
```

On debugging, I'm getting this log:

```
03-29 11:15:36.069 198-9920/? I/OMXCodec: [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] Crop 
rect is 368 x 272 @ (0, 0)
03-29 11:15:36.209 198-684/? E/MediaPlayerService: WFD client is not created 
03-29 11:15:36.229 198-9925/? I/OMXCodec: [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] Crop 
rect is 368 x 272 @ (0, 0)
03-29 11:15:36.359 15596-15596/zoptal.com.appegovidexample 
D/CropperActivity: ffmpeg : correct Loaded
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 
'/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Animated Gifs/VID-20170318- 
WA0000.mp4':

Metadata:

major_brand     : mp42

minor_version   : 1

compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom

creation_time   : 2017-03-10 14:32:13

Duration: 00:00:05.00, start: 0.080000, bitrate: 206 kb/s

  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv,  
  /smpte170m/bt709), 368x272, 203 kb/s, 14 fps, 100 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc 
  (default)

  Metadata:

 creation_time   : 2017-03-10 14:32:13

 handler_name    : Core Media Video

 [Parsed_crop_0 @ 0x41e47550] Invalid too big or non positive size for width 
 '630' or height '592'

 [Parsed_crop_0 @ 0x41e47550] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_crop_0

 Error opening filters!
 03-29 11:17:32.253 15596-15596/zoptal.com.appegovidexample 
  D/CropperActivity: Finished command : ffmpeg [Ljava.lang.String;@427f0d48
  03-29 11:17:32.273 15596-15596/zoptal.com.appegovidexample E/MediaPlayer: 
  Unable to create media player
```

EDIT:
I tried scaling the video by adding"scale=1280:720" to the command(as default crop rect based on video was 368 x 272 @ (0, 0)).Now, I'm getting this error:

```
 Metadata:

 creation_time   : 2017-03-10 14:32:13

 handler_name    : Core Media Video

 [NULL @ 0x41b65c80] Unable to find a suitable output format for 
 'crop=692:745:115:115'

 crop=692:745:115:115: Invalid argument
```

EDIT: I solved it in the following way:

```
        float[]ghi=  cropImageView.getCropPoints();
        int a= Math.round(ghi[0]);
        int b= Math.round(ghi[1]);
        int c= Math.round(ghi[2]);
        int d= Math.round(ghi[3]);
        String[] cmde = {"-i", path ,"-filter:v", "crop=" + 240 + ":" + 
        220 + ":" + a + ":" + b, "-c:a", "copy", videoPath};
        execFFmpegBinary(cmde);
```

Comment: Many Android users trying to use `ffmpeg` encounter issues related to quoting so the command gets parsed incorrectly.

Comment: obviously the commandline you are building is incorrect, my first guess is the output filename is just empty. to debug, add -report option as a first option it will write a file like "ffmpeg-20180330-164701.log" into the current directory, showing you the commandline ffmpeg was started with